# Are there search and dictionary panel applets available for Unity?

Tags: unity, software-recommendation, applet

Is there a search applet like OS X's and is there a dictionary applet like in Xubuntu and Kubuntu? If so, how do I get them? By applets, I mean the ones on the panel

Comment: What do you mean by applet? Application indicator?

Comment: At any rate, I did do a quick search on [this question listing panel applets ("*application indicators*")](http://askubuntu.com/q/30334/18612) and I couldn't find what you wanted there. Not sure if an online search would turn something else up, though; if someone finds them then they should also be added back to that list for convenience.

Comment: couldn't you just use the search function in the unity dash?

Answer (score 2):

### Artha

Artha is a handy English thesaurus having distinct features like look up on a global hot key press, passive notifications of a selected text's definitions, suggestions for misspelled words, etc. Once launched, it sits on the system tray monitoring for a pre-set hot key combination. When some text is selected on any window and the hotkey is pressed, it pops-up with the word looked-up. Should the user prefer passive notifications over the app. popping-up, this can be done by enabling the notifications option

**Artha** is available in **the Ubuntu Software** Centre for installation and come with a Panel indicator.
[image]